# Organising common code in django/python

Tags: python, django

Sometimes we need in auxiliary functions, classes etc.
Sometimes we put such entities into modules or packages.

Currently I have three variants:

1. Use **helpers** package or module.
2. Use **utils** package or module (like in Java).
3. Don't use something like it because it is anti pattern. If you have helpers then you have a application design problem.

What do you prefer?

Comment: For Django, I'd tend to put common utility code into the 'site' package, and within that organise it with meaningful names. E.g. don't call a module 'utils' or 'helpers', split it up into [multiple] modules with names based on what they actually do.

Comment: @tom-dalton Yep, but it is not possible every time. For example i have a functions make_ok_response() and make_error_response() that creates a soap responses. What is meaningful name for they?

Comment: `soap_response_factories`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with having helpers, but I think you chose wrong naming strategy. The name of the module or package should tell you what function it performs.

In your case you should name your helpers after the job they help you do. For example, `StringHelpers` or `UrlUtils`.